# Listening to a table and if a row inserted to it, will update another table

Tags: python, sql, mysql, sqlalchemy

T1 has 20 columns, and T2 has 15 columns which contains 5 columns of T1 and 10 null columns which are editable for the customer. Now, I want to write a piece of code in my python script to keep updating my T2 if a row inserted to T1. My customer only can see the T2 in the application. I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me in this regard.

This is my script and I am trying to add the updating statements to it:

```
def get_dispatches(db):
    query = f"""
        SELECT C1,
            C2,
            C3,
            C4,
            C5
        FROM T1
        """

    return pd.read_sql(text(query),db)

def get_plan(db):
    query = f"""
        SELECT * FROM T2;
        """
    return pd.read_sql(text(query),db)

con = get_sql_conn('T1schema')
df_dispatches_list = get_dispatches(con)


plan_con = get_sql_conn('T2schema')
df_plan_list = get_plan(plan_con)

result = df_dispatches_list.to_sql('T2',plan_con, schema='T2schema',if_exists='append',index=False)
print(result)


con.close()
plan_con.close()
```

Comment: Why duplicate the T1 columns in T2? Just put the editable columns in T2, along with a foreign key to T1, and use `JOIN` to combine it with T1 when you need both sets of data.

Comment: If you really need to duplicate the columns you can use a `TRIGGER` to create the T2 row whenever a row is inserted into T1.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for the information. I was thinking about the trigger. This is the error code whenever I want to execute the python script: IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '29477784-2022-11-16 23:16:05.000000' for key 'T2.PRIMARY'")

Comment: The error message seems clear, you're creating a duplicate primary key in T2.

Comment: So there's something wrong with how you're creating the T2 row in the T1 trigger. Without seeing the code I can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar about your first solution, I'm gonna search about it. But before that let me explain, T1 has been changed a lot and we need to fetch the data to T2 and add data to editable columns, so my script should always listen to the T1 to get the latest data and not copying duplicate data.

Comment: Use an `INSERT-or-UPDATE` statement to add or replace T2 rows based on T1. The specific syntax depends on what DBMS you're using. (SQLite, MySQL, SQL-Server, etc.).

Comment: @Barmar The abovementioned code is the actual code, I haven't written the trigger query yet. If I delete the T2 table in MySQL workbench then run the code, it will work properly. However, in the second time, I got this error as we already have the latest data in our T2. If I wanna automate this script and run it in K8S, it won't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists